# C# Sqlite ExecuteNonQuery returns 1 but no data inserted

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a very strange situation with sqlite:

Database: data.sqlite

Connection string:

```
string strDb = @"Data Source=C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\db.sqlite;Version=3;";
```

I use executeNonQuery to insert new row, it always return 1 (success), but **new data can not be read by other applications** such as DB browser for SQLite or PHP (DB is old, no new row).
However whenb I use executeReader to read, I see the data that was inserted before.

**I copy data into E: drive**, insert succeed, readble by DB browser for SQLite, **and everything works well**.

```
string strDb = @"Data Source=E:\db.sqlite;Version=3;";
```

I set permission for db file in C: drive to Everyone with full permission, nothing changes.

**Summary:** When I use sqlite with C#, data can not be read by other application (data in C:\ drive). If I place it into other place (such as E:), it works properly.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: C: does not matter but %ProgramFiles% - you where hit by virtualization when writing to the %ProgramFiles% path

Comment: I did it but no success. ***eg: E:\Program Files(x86)\db.sqlite***

Comment: Problem is why data can be insert and read by C# but other applications can not read it, and why when I move db into E:\ it works properly. Very strange

Comment: Whenever you write to a file in a special treated path like the ProgramFiles, Windows will virtualize that and nothing is written to the real file only to the virtualized one. Google for VirtualStore

Comment: Always avoid "C:\Program Files" for reading/writing something...

Comment: Thank you for very useful information. My app installed on Program Files with http server (nginx). Side question: should I move http into UserData folder ?

Comment: After C# insert, is the last modified date of the db file changed? can you read the previously inserted value through C# (or via sqlite3 cmd exe)?

Comment: @MachineLearning I can read the inserted row by C# but can not read by other apps. Modified date not changed after inserted. I think Sir Rufo right, reason is VirtualStore

Comment: @trinvh ok, does it means that you *can* find the *actual* sql db updated by C# under something like `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files(x86)\...` with modified date changed and data visibe also from other app?